# Find/color/mark text on other website

Tags: javascript, html, cross-domain

I want to alter text on another website. Let's say i want to color the heading *Find/color/mark text on other website* of this question red (without having access to the file/server itself). So when going to mywebsite.com/example you would see this page with a read heading.

Is there any smart way I can do this?

I have found several solutions, but nothing is really what i need:

1: A Browser-plugin. Then i would have full access to websites and could alter them, but i really don't want to force people to install a browserplugin.

2: Load the website through a server, alter the heading and then send it to the client. This is problematic because the server has to do the work before sending it. This might also break something (although the BASE-tag could be used to overcome some errors)

3: bookmarklet. I could write some javascript which gets appended to the actual page when the user clicks on the bookmarklet. The problem is that you user actively has to do something, which is something i don't want.

What i would like to do: Load the page in a iframe and somehow append a script to the content. I could show the webpage in a normal way and still alter the text to red. This is not possible as far as i know, but i hope you get a picture of what i want.

If you can help me in any way, or just point me in some direction, your help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you talking about something like [Greasemonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey)? It would run in your browser on the pages of your choosing without any input from you beyond the initial script.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, one cannot alter another website without access to the domain, or without access to the code. Generally, this is NOT recommended if you do not have permission.